# Sending Email from localhost(using NodeJS + Express) throws 'UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY'

Tags: node.js, ssl-certificate, sendgrid

I have setup SendGrid Email API SMTP service to send email from my app(using NodeJS with express). On sending email from my localhost, I get the below error:

```
Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1532:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:946:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:727:12) {
  code: 'UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY'
```

I tried options to disable and also with enable SSL certificates, but no luck.

```
npm set strict-ssl=false
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
npm config set cafile *.pem
```

I also tried setting the certificates(DigiCertGlobalRootCA & DigiCertTLSECCP384RootG5.crt.pem) on nodejs server startup(refer https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-use-ssltls-with-node-js/) but end up with same error.

Can you help me on resolving this issue. Do we need the CA certificates to send emails, how do I fix this problem, how do I set the certificates in NodeJS?

Comment: Most of the results on the web about this suggest that the [error is caused by a company firewall or proxy](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3742) and you need to include your proxy details or your company certificate. This [forum post](https://community.developer.visa.com/t5/Two-way-SSL-X-Pay-Token/Authorization-Credemtials-on-NodeJS/td-p/10900) suggests that the certificates should be in `.cer` format for Node, not `.crt`, perhaps that helps?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I set the certificates in .cer format for Node but still no luck. Below are the options tried so far.  
npm set strict-ssl false

npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/

npm set NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=<path>\DigiCertGlobalRootCA.cer

npm config set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0

Please suggest any further options.

Comment: What is the actual code you are running that is causing this error?

Comment: I am following https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-send-emails-with-node-js-using-sendgrid/ to setup email using SendGrid SMTP.
Following is code snippet:

const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
let mailOptions={from:constants.EMAIL_CONFIG.FROM,to:emailDetails.email, subject:emailDetails.subject, text:emailDetails.text,html:emailDetails.body};
sgMail.send(mailOptions)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response[0].statusCode)
      console.log(response[0].headers)
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error(error)
    })

Comment: Ok, so setting things in npm config isn’t going to solve this. Are you behind a corporate firewall or proxy?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Running on company laptop but not in VPN, that is, not in the corporate network.
Postman works fine!
A colleague told me that we have a "local Proxy" on the laptop and I need to go through this. And because this proxy has a self signed cert, I need to disable SSL validation or add it to a truststore.
Is a bit much for me to understand.

```
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail')
const apiKey = process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY;

sgMail.setApiKey(apiKey)
const msg = {
  to: 'aaa@bbb.com',
  from: 'ccc@ddd.com',
  subject: 'SendGrid test',
  text: 'Easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js'
}
sgMail
  .send(msg)
  .then(() => {
     console.log('Email sent')
  })
  .catch((error) => {
     console.error(error)
})
```

Comment: What kind of help do you need with this? Is it the same problem as described at the top of this page? Or can your code be used to solve that problem and you are only asking a follow up question?

Comment: Marco Forster, I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.